# Writing to a file from different methods

Tags: java

I've been working on a small project in Java. The program writes to a log file from different methods . But each time a method is used , the content of the file gets deleted and all what's written in it is the result of the last method.
here's a code snippet of the program :

```
// dir , log_file , exp_date and amount are declared in the code removed 
public static void WriteHeader() throws IOException
{
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(dir+"/"+log_file);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    Console console = System.console();
    exp_date = console.readLine("Enter a string here: ");
    bufferedWriter.write(exp_date);
    bufferedWriter.close();
}
public static void WriteNewLine() throws IOException
{
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(dir+"/"+log_file);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter2 = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    Console console = System.console();
    amount = console.readLine("Enter another string here :");
    bufferedWriter2.newLine();
    bufferedWriter2.write(amount);
    bufferedWriter2.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the writer in append mode http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File, boolean)

Comment: Do I need to declare the filewriter once with the boolean , or twice ?

Comment: try both and see yourself..:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to open file in `append` mode otherwise once you close the file and reopen it to write, it would erase previous data. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String, boolean)

```
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(dir+"/"+log_file, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
```

I am pretty sure FileWriter has an overloaded constructor for appending to a file instead of overwriting a file

I would also check if the file exists first.

```
file.exists();
```